# how to show composite function ff(x) in arrow diagram.

Tags: functions

If f={(1,2),(2,3)}. what is ff(1) and ff(2).show in arrow diagram.I tried doing it and I got ff(1)=3 but I can't find ff(2).

Comment: Correct: $f(2)=3$ and $3$ is not in $f$'s domain.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).